# Custom overlay over normal Android usage

Tags: android, customization

I want to build an android app for educational purpose and I don't know if my idea is feasible.

I want to display a bar with some text on the bottom of the screen and allow the user to keep using the operating system.

**Example** browsing the web and been able to seen the text bar at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't overlay your view and allow the user to interact with background activities at the same time.